# How to check if EventMachine::Connection is open?

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

I have a handle to a Connection object in Event Machine: http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/EventMachine/Connection.html

How can I check if the connection is open or closed at any point of time?
I don't see any method specified in the API.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to implement it yourself, which is pretty easy.

```
class SampleConnection < EM::Connection
  attr_accessor :connected
  def connection_completed
    connected = true
  end

  def connected?
    !!connected
  end

  def unbind
    connected = false
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, it is easy to implement it myself. I wanted to double check that there is no solution already readily available in the class.